# How to get Dynatrace Managed Cluster Token Automatically after installation?

Tags: dynatrace

I am trying to automate my deployment of Dynatrace Managed, and the Cluster API seems useful for most of the setup, but I'm having trouble automating getting a token to access the Cluster API.

The Cluster API has an endpoint to create new Tokens, but I need a Token to authorize and use that endpoint, so it's a circular dependency.

I noticed an "afterInstallation" token in the Cluster Management Console (CMC), is there any way I might be able to retrieve that token? My idea was to somehow grab the "afterInstallation" token right after installing dynatrace managed, but I don't know how.

I have ssh access to the nodes in the cluster and the admin username/password. The manual way would be to login to the CMC and go to Settings > API Tokens > Cluster tokens > Generate token.

Is there a way to generate or obtain a token via CLI that doesn't depend on already having a token?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy with the --install-silent option (along with --initial-environment... etc.) for the first node to skip manual UI setup. See: https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/shortlink/managed-custom-install#initial-configuration-parameters

Look in the installer log file for the afterInstallation API key and endpoint for the configuration API after the first node is installed.
The IP of the server will also be the seed node address (--seed-ip) could be used for subsequent nodes.

In this way, you can fully automate a multi-cluster setup with the initial seed token from the first node (--seed-auth) to perform an unattended install. See https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/shortlink/managed-custom-install#install-managed-cluster

Noting that the cluster token is used for joining nodes to the cluster and expires after 3hrs.

If you require long-term access to the cluster configuration API to perform actions not available with the initial setup, then you'd have to generate a cluster API token from the cluster management console (CMC) with the ClusterTokenManagement permission, since this would give you access to generate new tokens on-demand. See: https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/shortlink/api-cluster-tokens-create-new#authentication